# Forms array error while unit test using jasmine and karma

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'am writing unit test case for angular application version 9. but im getting below error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

how to spy getFormControls methos or else i have to use spyonproperty, i have tried to set spyonproperty but getting different error.

iam new to jasmine unit test getting struck in most of place,

ts:

```
  get getFormControls() {
    const control = this.relTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    return control;
  }

submit() {
    this.messageService.clear();

/*     const formGroup = this.getFormControls.controls[this.isEdit.length - 1] as FormGroup;
    const rNameValue = formGroup.controls['rName'].value;
    const pEntityValue = formGroup.controls['pEntity'].value;
    const cEntityValue = formGroup.controls['cEntity'].value;


    this.new_rel_Data.push({
      'rName': rNameValue,
      'pEntity': pEntityValue,
      'cEntity': cEntityValue
    });  */



     this.new_rel_Data.push({
      'rName': this.getFormControls.controls[this.isEdit.length - 1].get('rName').value,
      'pEntity': this.getFormControls.controls[this.isEdit.length - 1].get('pEntity').value,
      'cEntity': this.getFormControls.controls[this.isEdit.length - 1].get('cEntity').value
    }); 

    this.relTemp.addReldata(this.new_rel_Data).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.loadRelTemp();
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'New value inserted successfully', sticky: true });
      },
      (err) => {
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: err.message, detail: 'Please contact Admin', sticky: true });
      },
      () => {
        const control = this.relTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
        control.clear();
        this.enableSubmit = false;
      }
    );

  }
```

spec:

```
 // submit for insert new value
  fit('Submit() Relational data', () => {

    let data = [ 'foo' ];
    component.new_rel_Data = data;

  fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(component, 'submit').and.callThrough();
    

    spyOn(relTemplateUpdateService, 'addReldata').and.returnValue(
      of({ result: { status: 200 } })
    );
    component.submit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(relTemplateUpdateService.addReldata).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have errors like these: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, usually that means you forgot to add/mock something in your tests (although this could happen anywhere in real code as well).

In this particular case, you missed to mock either `relTable` or the result of `getFormControls` getter.

In any case, I would probably mock the getter like this:

```
spyOnProperty(relTemplateUpdateService, 'getFormControls').and.returnValue(new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      rName: new FormControl('rName'),
      pEntity: new FormControl('pEntity'),
      cEntity: new FormControl('cEntity'),
    }),
  ]));
```

Since TypeScript doesn't allow assigning to a getter, you would probably need to use `spyOnProperty` method instead of something like `relTemplateUpdateService.getFormControls = ...`. If it wasn't a getter, then you could have also mocked `this.relTable` with the same return value but I personally didn't find this working with getter.

Also you should check (probably better in real code; unless you're sure you don't need to) that `this.isEdit` is always greater than 0, otherwise, you'll get another error with undefined.

Comment: still getting same error and i have change relTemplateUpadteService to component like below because getFormControls is a method which inside component.   spyOnProperty(component, 'getFormControls').and.returnValue(new FormArray([         new FormGroup({           rName: new FormControl('rName'),           pEntity: new FormControl('pEntity'),

Comment: You might need to share more details (code) since for me it looks to be working. It could be a totally different area.